# Threading vs Multiprocess vs Twisted in Python

Tags: python, mysql, multithreading, twisted, multiprocessing

Can I get help converting this code from Threading to Mutliprocess.
Then can anyone help  convert this code usinf twisted.

Would there be a gain from using twisted to upload db
within Python vs External tools.

```
import  os, pyodbc, sys, threading, Queue


class WorkerThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, queue):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.queue = queue

    def run(self):
        while 1:
            try: # take a job from the queue
                type  = self.queue.get_nowait()

            except Queue.Empty:
                raise SystemExit

            try:
               cxn = pyodbc.connect('DSN=MySQL;PWD=MLML;Option=3') 
               csr = cxn.cursor()    
               # Inserts,update, CRUD

            except:
               # count = count +1
                print 'DB Error', type

if __name__ == '__main__':
    connections =  25

    sml = ('A', 'B', 'C','D',)
    # build a queue with tuples
    queue = Queue.Queue()

    for row in sml:
        if not row or row[0] == "#":
            continue
        queue.put(row) 

    threads = []
    for dummy in range(connections):
        t = WorkerThread(queue)
        t.start()
        threads.append(t)

    # wait for all threads to finish
    for thread in threads:
        thread.join()

    sys.stdout.flush()

#csr.close()
#cxn.close()
print 'Finish'
```

Comment: Did you have a specific question, or did you really just want us to write code for you?

Comment: I'm having trouble reading your variably indented python-pseudo code. Could you mind correcting your indentation. Or even post a working example?

Comment: +1  nmichaels This does not look like a question.

Answer (score 1):

**Updated**: JP mentioned the [**txpostgres**](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/txpostgres) and [**txmysql**](https://github.com/hybridlogic/txMySQL) modules, which I wasn't aware of. These allow Twisted to access both databases asynchronously (without using a thread pool).

Note that if you decide to use Twisted's enterprise adbapi, it will end up using a thread pool to handle database connections, roughly the equivalent of your existing example.  See the [docs on using Twisted's enterprise database module](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/10.2.0/core/howto/rdbms.html).

You should be able to directly translate your thread/queue-based code to use the multiprocessing module, by replacing your threads with `Process` instances, and uing the multiprocessing `Queue` implementation. See the [multiprocessing docs](http://docs.python.org/release/2.6.6/library/multiprocessing.html).

Comment: You can use txpostgres or txmysql to talk to postgres and mysql without threads.

Comment: @JP I wasn't aware of those projects, thanks. I updated the answer.